# Proving an logical identity for the zero one laws

Tags: logic, random-graphs

With identity I mean that there is an equivalent statement. With logicall I mean that this statement deals with EF-games.

I want to prove that

A function $p(n)\in [0,1]$ satisfies the Zero one laws iff for every first order logical statement $A$ over the signature for graphs $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Pr[((G,n,p(n)))\models A]=1 \vee 0$

I want to show now that

A function satisfies the zero one laws iff for every $t,G(n,p(n)),H(m,p(m)):\lim_{m,n\rightarrow\infty}Pr[\texttt{Duplicator wins EHR[G,n,p(n),H(m,p(m)),t]}]=1$

$\Leftarrow$ is proved in the book (proof Theorem 10.7.4). How can I prove the other direction?

[image: hh]
[image: zz]
[image: qq]

Comment: "A function $p(n)\in[0,1]$ satisfies the Zero one laws iff for every first order logical statement A over the signature for graphs $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[G(n,p(n))\models A] =1$ or $0$" looks like a definition. What is there to prove?

Comment: What I want to show is that for every first order statement $A$ and every we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[G(n,p(n))\models A] =1$  if and only if $\forall t\in\mathbb{N}, G(n,p(n)),H(m,p(m)):\lim_{m,n\rightarrow\infty}Pr[\texttt{Duplicator wins EHR[G,n,p(n),H(m,p(m)),t]}]=1$

Comment: Hint: Lemma 10.7.3 can be stengthened to be an if and only if. You can also prove a lemma that says if the spoiler wins EHR$[G,H,t]$ for some $t$, then there is some $A$ such that $A\models G$ but $A\not\models H$ (or vice versa).

Comment: I was thinking, maybe even better is to show that for every $t$, there is some $A$ such that $t(A) = t$. From this and the strengthening of 10.7.3 the above follows.